# Swift 4 Playground - getting object/result from JSON

Tags: json, swift, swift4, swift-playground

I am using Swift 4 in Playgrounds (MacOS), testing my code as a beginner... I would like to get the object / result of title from a remote JSON.

The code is working until the point 'print(object.title)' which I was hoping it would return the value of the first title in the imported JSON.

```
    import Foundation
    import PlaygroundSupport

    PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

    // Create structer of Post
    struct Post: Codable {
        var userId: Int
        var title: String
        var body: String
    }

    // Remote JSON to Structed Object
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
    let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let datastring = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        // Decode data to object
        let object = try decoder.decode(Post.self, from: jsonData)
        print(object.title) 
    }
    catch {
        // Error Catch
        //print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please (learn to) **read** the JSON. The root object is an array (represented by `[]`) so you need to decode `[Post]` and a loop to print all items:

```
let object = try decoder.decode([Post].self, from: jsonData)
for post in object {
    print(post.title) 
}
```

and never, never, never ignore errors

```
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi Vadian, Thanks for your quick answer.... The addition of your code results in the following error:  Playground execution failed:

error: MyPlayground.playground:16:14: error: type 'Post' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
        for user in object {
                    ^

Comment: Thanks, error was only commented out as I am testing... But yes it will have error handling.... But I still have the error.....

Comment: Once again, you have to decode `[Post]`, not `Post`. Please note the brackets.

Comment: Ahhhh many Thanks you star, didn't see the brackets..... That works, Thank you very much Vadian :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, pay attention on all features of Swift4. I mean Encoding, Decoding and Serialization in Swift 4. So, you can play with it. I've added code for Playground:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

typealias JSONModel = [JSONModelElement]

class JSONModelElement: Codable {
    let userID, id: Int?
    let title, body: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "userId"
        case id, title, body
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

if let jsonModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(JSONModel.self, from: jsonData) {
    for element in jsonModel {
        print(element.title)
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Vadim - Your sample code look great, I will have a play :)